# Karate - How to validate output as a list of specific json format?

Tags: unit-testing, karate

This is my expected output:

```
[{name: 'ehsan'},{name: 'ali'},{name: 'mammad'}]
```

How to validate my output that matches a list of variable length of a json with this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign that list  to a variable and then use match each

```
def array = [{name: 'ehsan'},{name: 'ali'},{name: 'mammad'}] 
Then match each array contains
"""
       {
          name : '#string'
       }
"""
```